# Blurry text when generating and printing an ID card

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, image-processing, text-processing

I am generating ID cards via .NET and I am having a problem where the dynamic text I insert appears so blurry that I have to use a bold font for it to be begrudgingly accepted.

What I'm currently doing:

1. Grab the image "frame".
2. Grab the employee's photograph.
3. Merge them.
4. Create a new bitmap from the generated image.
5. **Add two sets of text on top of the bitmap (FontBrush color set to Black).**
6. Save the image in `PNG` and with the highest quality I can get.

Is there something to be done when generating the image to improve the printing on PVC ID cards?

```
    public TextOnImage AddText(string message, Font font, PointF point)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Image))
        {
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            //g.TextContrast = 0;
            //g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias; <-- Still didn't work
            g.DrawString(message, font, Brush, point, StringFormat);
        }

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: How are you actually printing these things from a web app? Is it just the text that is blurry? Sounds like some kind of base resolution problem.

Comment: @jamietre From the web app I generate an image the user downloads and prints using the operating system (corporate / controlled app).

Comment: But everything else looks clean (except the text)? I've had no problem rendering print-quality text with `Grahphics`, maybe you can post the code where you render text onto the image.

Comment: @jamietre: everythings else is Ok, yes. I edited to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this helped, I ended up generating a PDF so the printer would read the font directly. This way, the printer doesn't try to "paint" the font's edges, and simply prints the text in an optimized way.

More information: [Overlay text over an image background and convert to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573150/overlay-text-over-an-image-background-and-convert-to-pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using GDI+, try turning off Anti-Aliasing by setting the TextRenderingHint on the graphics object to another value: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssazt6bs.aspx

Comment: I did that, but the problem persisted. The problem is that I convert the text + frame to an image and then print it. I tested printing the text from a content like MS Word / PDF and they display correctly when printing the text directly instead of an image. Any help?

Comment: Although this helped, I ended up generating a PDF so the printer would read the font directly.